# How to reclassify and sum values after calculating monthly MODIS averages in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, modis, reclassify

I am trying to calculate monthly average vegetation condition index (VCI) for Ukraine from a MODIS image collection. I then want to reclassify the values to:

```
1 for values between 0 and 0.4
0 for values between 0.4 and 1
```

Finally I want to sum the monthly reclassified values to get a single image showing the summed reclassified VCI for each pixel across Ukraine.

I get the following error:

```
springsum_vci_reclass_sum: Layer error: ImageCollection.fromImages, argument 'images': Invalid type.
Expected type: List<Image<unknown bands>>.
Actual type: List<List<Image<[EVI]>>>.
Actual value: [[<Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>], [<Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>], [<Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>], [<Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>], [<Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>], [<Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>], [<Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>], [<Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>], [<Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>], [<Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>], [<Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>], [<Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>], [<Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>], [<Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>], [<Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>], [<Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>], [<Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>], [<Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>], [<Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>], [<Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>, <Image<[EVI]>>]]
```

Code that is causing the error (sorry if it is messy):

```
//import country boundaries
var countries = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017');
//Subset Ukraine from countries
var ukr = ee.Feature(
  countries
   .filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_na', 'Ukraine'))
    .first()
);
print("ukr",ukr);


//get MODIS EVI collection
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13A1').select('EVI');
  
// filter images by year
var reference = ee.ImageCollection(collection.filterDate('2001-01-01', '2020-12-31'))
  .sort('system:time_start');
print("reference",reference);

//filter out images from march - august season
var springsum = reference.filter(ee.Filter.dayOfYear(59,243));

//calulate min and max of full series (mam 2001-2020) for each pixel
var springsum_min = springsum.min();
var springsum_max = springsum.max();
//mask out agriculture
var springsum_min_agrimask = springsum_min.multiply(agrimask_UKR);
var springsum_max_agrimask = springsum_max.multiply(agrimask_UKR);

var startyear = 2001;
var endyear = 2020;

var startdate = ee.Date.fromYMD(startyear,1,1);
var enddate = ee.Date.fromYMD(endyear + 1, 1, 1);

var years = ee.List.sequence(startyear, endyear);
var months = ee.List.sequence(3, 8);

print("years",years);
print("months",months);

var vci_bot_springsum = springsum_max_agrimask.subtract(springsum_min_agrimask);

//calculate average VCI for each month (Mar-Aug) between 2001-2020, sum for each pixel and reclassify values to 0 or 1 
var springsum_vci = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
      years.map(function (y) {
          return months.map(function(m) {
           var mon = springsum
                    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
                    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
                    .select("EVI").mean()
                    .multiply(agrimask_UKR)
                    .subtract(springsum_min_agrimask)
                    .divide(vci_bot_springsum);
            return mon.where(mon.gt(0).and(mon.lte(0.4)), 1)
                    .where(mon.gt(0.4).and(mon.lte(1)), 0)
                    .set('year', y)
                    .set('month', m)
                    .set('system:time_start', ee.Date.fromYMD(y, m, 1));

})})).sum();


print("check");

//add to map
Map.addLayer(springsum_vci, {
  min: 0,
  max: 40,
  palette: [
    'darkred','red','yellow','green','darkgreen'
  ]}, 'springsum_vci_reclass_sum');


//export  
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: springsum_vci,
  description: 'springsum_vci_reclass_sum',
  region:ukr,
  scale: 500
});
```

Please find a link here to the full code [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/691bd68cd0f728c981afc5cc37f1bca0)

Comment: You should put a functional link code in your question.

Comment: @xunilk thank you, done

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: @xunilk should work now

Comment: Now it is working but Agrimask_UKR_Copernicus_2019_resamp' not found.

Comment: @xunilk I just made the file public so it should work now

Answer (score 0):

Fixed simply by adding "flatten" before summing. Working code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/ab0990a6fc9542ca2fa7a1da1079ed16)

```
var springsum_vci = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
      years.map(function (y) {
          return months.map(function(m) {
           var mon = springsum
                    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
                    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
                    .select("EVI").mean()
                    .multiply(agrimask_UKR)
                    .subtract(springsum_min_agrimask)
                    .divide(vci_bot_springsum);
            return mon.where(mon.gt(0).and(mon.lte(0.4)), 1)
                    .where(mon.gt(0.4).and(mon.lte(1)), 0)
                    .set('year', y)
                    .set('month', m)
                    .set('system:time_start', ee.Date.fromYMD(y, m, 1));

})})).flatten().sum();
```